# Where to override JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA for setting custom token expiration time?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using django-rest-framework-jwt for authenticating users on my RESTful web service. The problem is every time we issue a token it gets expired after 5 minutes. I have gone through the following documentation 
http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings

It says that we can override this behaviour by overriding JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA variable, but doesn't tells us how ? I've tried overriding it in project's settings.py and in views.py but its not working. How and where should we override these variables in general for our django-rest application ?

Answer (score 5):

In `settings.py`:

```
import datetime

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*set the value in the app.config[]:*, just figured this out myself and tested it, it's working.

```
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

Comment: the question is not about Flask though

Answer (score 1):

You can add the additional settings within settings.py. Just make sure you `import datetime` for the `timedelta`.

Answer (score 0):

despite the fact that the correct answer is given I want to add little bit extra explanation:

1. [Here](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) is a comprehensive info how to set `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA`
2. Usually Web Token is not stored at database and because of it increasing of expiration time is a bad practice. Lifetime of token should be short because it can't be invalidated. Token is active until expired.
3. Because of ② authentication workflow is little bit different then usual session tokens:

   - **session token**: Once issued session token expiration time updating at database based on user behavior. No user actions for N minutes => Token expired. However when user logging out we able to revoke token and invalidate it regardless it expiration status and time. That allows to set expiration time longer
   - **JSON web token**: Once issued web token expiration time can't be updated. Once issued web token can't be revoked. We can't control issued token at backend. It is not stored at DB. Let's say that your token lifetime is 1 day and one of tokens was compromised when issued. Someone who knows this token id able to access your service for 24 hours. And you will must to revoke **all tokens** to invalidate one bad token. All users will be forcedly logged out.

     - So correct workflow for JWT is: **A.** Access token is issued for short time, **B.** Token expired, **C.** Frontend app detected that access denied (error code 401), **D.** Frontend app request for new token using refresh token. (transparently for user) **E.** When user logging out refresh token should be deleted from DB, **F.** Access token is expired and refresh token is deleted at DB, so current auth credentials can't be used anymore.

You (abstract reader of this answer) have to think before copy-paste:

> `app.config['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = datetime.timedelta(days=10)`